# Interface incorrectly extends interface

Tags: typescript, interface

```
class One {
  controls: { [key: string]: number };
}

interface Two<T> extends One {
  controls: { [key in keyof T]: number }
}
```

I get an error that:

> TS2430: Interface 'Two' incorrectly extends interface 'One'.
>     Types of property 'controls' are incompatible.
>       Type '{ [key in keyof T]: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: number; }'

In typescript playground ([click](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20One%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20controls%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Two%3CT%3E%20extends%20One%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20controls%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)) everything seems to be okay. What is it happening?

Typescript version: 2.4.2

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue in 2.4, which got fixed in 2.5. You can have a look at the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14548). Basically in 2.4 this is not allowed, in 2.5 it was explicitly allowed:

> Mapped types over `keyof T` [are] subtypes of types with string index signatures